# Could not format the selected date time using Jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I need to format the date and time while selecting value from `Jquery datetimepicker` . I am explaining my code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>jQuery Datepicker UI Example - Demo Preview</title>
       <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script> 


       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
       <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.min.css"/>
       <script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

       <style type="text/css">
           .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.bottom {
               top: 26px !important;
           }
       </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 top-buffer">
                    <h3>DatePicker Example</h3>
                    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-buffer"></div>
       </div>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ format:'dd-mm-yyyy'});
           });
       </script>
   </body>
<html>
```

Here I need after selecting the value from calender the input field should have the value format like `dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii AM/PM  or 23-10-2018 1.30 PM`.

Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: "*selecting the value*" - how, exactly, are you "selecting the value"?   Using `$("#datetimepicker").val()` or `$("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker("getDate")` or something else?  Selecting the text and pressing ctrl-c?

Comment: When I am selecting date from calender its displaying on the input field.

Comment: Ah - you mean when the datepicker popups up and you "select" a date ("pick" a date) to be displayed in the input.

Comment: @freedomn-m : Yes..and I need to change that datetime format.

Comment: Did you try changing the format that you've already specified?  `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ format:'dd-mm-yyyy'});`

Comment: @freedomn-m: Its giving the unexpected output.(`i.e-2424-1010-18181818`)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.   It's giving that because you've not used the datepicker date formatting variables - where `y` means 2 digit year (so `yyyy` means the 2 digit year 4 times - ie `18181818`).  Have a read of http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate   You probably want `dd-mm-yy` (from the doc above).  But you mention 'date *time* picker' - while the jquery-ui is only a *datepicker* (no time) - so **are you using a different picker?** As you're getting duplicates, I would suggest trying just `'d-m-y'` in the first instance, but test with dates before Oct.

Comment: try format:'d.m.Y H:i'

Comment: @SooriyaDasanayake : Yes but its still 24 hours time format. Can it be 12 hour time format ?

Comment: Updated my answer...

Comment: Given the plethora of `jquery.datetimepicker`s available, can you let us know the source(url, not js) of the one that you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format:'d.m.Y H:i:a',
        formatTime:'h:i:a'

        });
    });
```